# NetBeans Java ME project configuration

Tags: java, mobile, netbeans, java-me, midlet

I have a task: fix some problems in existing Java ME project. I open it in NetBeans, Java ME is installed at my system (Fedora).
There is a problem: I don't know how to launch this project. I click the launch button and get this:

```
Starting emulator in execution mode
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/username/Загрузки/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/username/Загрузки/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so: /home/username/Загрузки/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so: неправильный класс ELF: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
```

(Sorry for russian words in log, there's Загрузки=Downloads and "неправильный класс" = wrong class. I didn't translate it in log cause I'm not sure how it types in english NetBeans).

I'm trying to set another configuration in the top of NB window - from DefaultConfiguration to, for example, DefaultColorPhone. But there's another problem with this configuration: cannot find every class in program: MIDlet, CommandListener, even String.

How to fix it and launch the project? Thanks.

UPD, also there's:

```
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with JDK: WTK requires 32-bit version of JDK, and doesn't work with 64-bit version.